# Updating span color on a hover

Tags: html, css, colors, discourse

I am attempting to update span color on hover however I am unable to do so. I am able to update the background color, the size, etc however I am unable to update the font color.

HTML

```
<div class="subcategories">
     <span class="subcategory">
         <a class="badge-wrapper box" href="/c/anybus/anybus-embedded">
             <span class="badge-category-bg" style="background-color: #808281;"></span>
             <span style="color: #FFFFFF;" data-drop-close="true" class="badge-category clear-badge">My Span Text</span>
         </a>
     </span>
```

CSS I am trying to use:

```
.subcategories .subcategory a:hover span{
    color: #6D6D6D;
}
```

Comment: The answers are right about the cascade, but recommending `!important` is not such a good idea.  This paves the road to CSS hell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your inline CSS is overriding the color.

Either remove the inline CSS or add the important tag in your style sheet.

This will work: 
Although it's best practice not to user inline CSS so I advise you move it out of your HTML.

```
.subcategories .subcategory a:hover span{
    background-color: #6D6D6D;
    color: red !important;
}
```

Comment: I love you haha I can't accept as answer for 5 minutes but you got it. 

Edit: Also I cannot remove the inline css.

Answer (score 0):

The reason its not working is because you have inline styles on the span

`<span style="color: #FFFFFF;"`

You can override this by using !important in your css

```
.subcategories .subcategory a:hover span{
    color: #6D6D6D !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the following inline style, then your hover will work.

```
style="color: #FFFFFF;"
```

Instead, style with CSS like this:

```
.subcategories .subcategory a span{
   color: #ffffff;
}
```